# Spring batch unit test don't autowiring bean

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

I'm using Spring-boot 3.1.4 and Spring batch Framework 5.0.3.

First Question : When I launch my project with Spring-boot all my bean has been instanciate and i can use @Autowiring to inject them.
When i launch a End-to-End test, all my bean is not instanciate and i have this error.

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.job.MiniTask' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Did i forget test dependancies ?

Test class

```
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = { JobConfigurationTest.class })
class DemoApplicationTests {

     @Autowired
     private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
    @Test
    public void testJob(Job job) throws Exception {
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        Assertions.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}
```

Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager,MiniTask miniTask){
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository).tasklet(miniTask,transactionManager).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
    }

}
```

SpringBootApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args));
    }
}
```

Tasklet

```
@Component("miniTask")
public class MiniTask implements Tasklet {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MiniTask.class);

    public MiniTask() {
        LOG.info("Tasklet constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        LOG.info("Launch task");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

JobConfigurationTest class

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfigurationTest extends JobConfiguration {

}
```

Second Question : When i launch my project my doesn't launch automatically and i have only one job in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not share the content of `JobConfigurationTest` which is imported by the test class, but it seems there is no bean of type `Job` defined in it, hence the error. So to fix this issue, you need to define a bean of type `Job` in that class.

With Spring Boot, I would recommend using `@SpringBootTest`, which will load the main application context (ie the production one in which your job is defined), so there is no need to create a test context unless you want to override the main one.

The following works (tested with Spring Boot 3.1.5, project generated from start.spring.io with this [configuration](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.1.5&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=batch,h2)).

Job configuration class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("hello world");
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        }, transactionManager)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }


}
```

Main application class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    void testJob(@Autowired Job job) throws Exception {
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        Assertions.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: In you answer, do you mean to use ***@SpringBootTest*** with Spring boot and not ***@SpringBatchTest*** ?

Comment: By the way , do you know if i need to implements two differents data sources if i want Spring batch technical table in a embedded database ? Or Spring batch have an default option ?

Comment: Yes, I meant `@SpringBootTest`, I fixed the answer. Thanks. There is no need to use a different datasource for batch meta-data, but nothing prevents you from doing that.